# SymPy, simplification / substitution using known patterns or sub-expressions

Tags: python, substitution, sympy, symbolic-math, symbolic-computation

I have the following expression:

```
from sympy import pi, sin, cos, var, simplify
var('j,u,v,w,vt,wt,a2,t,phi')

u0 = v*a2*sin(pi*j/2 + pi*j*t*phi**(-1)/2) + pi*vt*a2*cos(pi*j/2 + pi*j*t*phi**(-1)/2)*j*phi**(-1)/2 + pi*w*a2*cos(pi*j/2 + pi*j*t*phi**(-1)/2)*j*phi**(-1)
```

Which can be simplified:

```
print simplify(u0)
#a2*(pi*j*vt*cos(pi*j*(phi + t)/(2*phi)) + 2*pi*j*w*cos(pi*j*(phi + t)/(2*phi)) + 2*phi*v*sin(pi*j*(phi + t)/(2*phi)))/(2*phi)
```

Given the sub-expressions:

```
bj = pi*j*(phi + t)/(2*phi)
cj = j*pi/(2*phi)
```

Currently I substitute manually `bj` and `cj` in the simplified `u0` expression to get:

```
u0 = a2*(v*sin(bj) + cj*vt*cos(bj) + 2*cj*w*cos(bj))
```

Is it possible to use SymPy to achieve that, avoiding the manual substitution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess what you are missing is that `subs` will replace arbitrary expressions, not just symbols

```
>>> print simplify(u0).subs({pi*j*(phi + t)/(2*phi): bj, j*pi/(2*phi): cj})
a2*(pi*j*vt*cos(bj) + 2*pi*j*w*cos(bj) + 2*phi*v*sin(bj))/(2*phi)
```

(I used `simplify` because that is what results in the `pi*j*(phi + t)/(2*phi)` instead of `pi*j/2 + pi*j*t/(2*phi)`, but it's not otherwise required)

Read http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.3/tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution for more information about substitution and replacement.  If you want to do more advanced replacement, take a look at the [`replace`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.3/modules/core.html?highlight=replace#sympy.core.basic.Basic.replace) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can find common subexpressions with the `cse` routine.

Comment: is it possible to pass to `cse` the sub-expressions that it should look for?

Comment: The point of `cse` is to find the expressions for you. If you know the common subexpressions, why would you need to search for them? If on the other hand your question is about substituting expressions, just use `subs` or any of the other routines mentioned in `subs` docstring. Check out the sympy tutorial http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: I have to search for them because sometimes they are not obviously visible, otherwise I could just replace in a text editor or similar. See for example `cj`, its sub-expression is inside `u0` but not explicitly separated...

Comment: So just use `cse`. I don't understand does or doesn't do that you want different. Also, using a text editor to do symbolic manipulation sounds like a really bad idea...